# Flutter app not launching on simulator. It exits because of not 'return a valid pid nor a launch error'

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, simulator

Flutter app launching shows error:

> An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=3):
> Application launch for '{com.package.name}' did not return a valid pid nor a launch error.
> No such process

Can anyone please help out with this error?

Comment: Try quitting simulator and re-run project.

Comment: are you on mac os or windows? Also whats your IDE?

Comment: Mac  OS @Moritz.

Comment: you can try to build it in xcode itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting again after quitting simulator made it run.

Comment: Did you install Rosseta in the mean-time? I've found the same pid issue without rosseta but the simulator is debuggable with because the simulator seems to be intel specific.

Comment: Didn't expect to fix. Eventually it worked. I played so Flutter setting and had this error. Just cmd+q and reopen simulator fixed.